# Stock how to add borrow fees to taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, tax-deduction

When doing taxes, how to account for stock borrow fees for hard to borrow stocks.  Can you deduct this from your income?

Say I short Company abc

```
Cost: $5000
Proceeds: $6000
Borrow fee: $3000
```

So is this a -$2000 loss.  Where to put this on your tax return?  Can you say the proceeds is $3000 instead of $6000?

There is also a section called "Other Fees paid" in IB tax forms.  Where to put this as well?

Comment: added tag united-states based on other questions you have asked.

Comment: That would make sense to me; the fee is part of the cost of producing the income and should count against it. But I don't do options, and what makes sense may not be what's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Investment interest expense is subject to specific rules and AMT treatment. It is deducted via [Form 4952](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-4952).

However, [borrow fees may be under a different treatment](https://www.forbes.com/sites/greatspeculations/2018/07/13/investment-fees-are-not-deductible-but-borrow-fees-are/?sh=2ee473522fe9). You may have to consult a tax advisor about this one.

You will have to read [Publication 550](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-publication-550) for the exact rules about deducting interest and other investment expenses. Note certain investment expense deductions were eliminated from Tax Year 2018-2025 by the Tax Cuts and Jobs Act of 2017.